# App crashing when trying to change profile photo

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am working in the edit profile portion of my application. When I try to change and update a users profile photo. The app crashes and I get this error

`reason: 'URL scheme must be one of gs://, http://, or https://`

When I create a new profile and add a profile photo or if I upload a photo it works fine but when I try to change the profile photo I get this. It will first remove the profile photo and update ( leaving the image view gray when a user doesn't have a photo) then when I try to rechange the photo again it will crash.

Here is the code I have.

```swift
func updateProfileImage() {
        guard imageChanged == true else { return }
        guard let currentUid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
        guard let user = self.user else { return }

        Storage.storage().reference(forURL: user.profileImageUrl).delete(completion: nil)

        let filename = NSUUID().uuidString

        guard let updatedProfileImage = profileImageView.image else { return }

        guard let imageData = updatedProfileImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.3) else { return }

        STORAGE_PROFILE_IMAGES_REF.child(filename).putData(imageData, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in

            if let error = error {
                print("Failed to upload image to storage with error: ", error.localizedDescription)
            }

            STORAGE_PROFILE_IMAGES_REF.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
                USER_REF.child(currentUid).child("profileImageUrl").setValue(url?.absoluteString, withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in

                    guard let userProfileController = self.userProfileController else { return }
                    userProfileController.fetchCurrentUserData()

                    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                })
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exact line throws that error?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Hi Frank, It doesn't give me a line.. just a full on crash and takes me to the AppDelegate. If that makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you **check URL is valid** or not using a **guard**.

```
  guard let urlis = yourUrl else{
  // url is nill.
      return
      }
if let url = NSURL(string: urlis) {
  // your image code  
  }
else{
  // url is invalid.
  return
  }
```

**Add Exception Breakpoint**: This quick tip will save you a lot of debugging time!. So Xcode will stop where the exception is caught.

In your project, go to the Breakpoint Navigator[image], click on the ’+’ button and ’Add Exception Breakpoint…’

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Going to try this piece of code out now.

Comment: Figured it out.  I needed to make sure that I use the non-optional value of the url, in other words:
guard let imageUrl = url?.absoluteString else { return } Ill accept your answer because its the same thing and put me on the right track on where to look!